# For IF Else loop not stopping when cells are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating several macro's to fill in values in an excel sheet based on formulas so that the file doesn't get to heavy to process.

I'm using for `if else` with in the `if` statement the condition to check if the cell itself and a cell in another column is empty. If these cells are empty no value needs to be put in the destination cell.
If the cells are not empty, first I fill in the formula and then I make sure only the value remains.

For the cells which didn't need to be filled in however, the formula is filled in.

I've tried several types of loops, I also exported the modules, removed them and imported them again, but this doesn't work.

I've started with the code below:

```
Sub ActionCI()

i = 4
x = 4
' x is column number of column which needs to be filled in

For i = 4 To 100
    If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = "" And _
         IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, 2).Value)) Then Exit For
    End if
    Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = "=IFNA(INDEX('PLANNED FOR ARRIVAL'!G:G,MATCH([@REFERENCE],'PLANNED FOR ARRIVAL'!D:D,0)),"""")"
    Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Then I tried:

```
Sub ActionCI()

i = 4
x = 4
' x is column number of column which needs to be filled in

For i = 4 To 100
    If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = "" And _
        IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, 2).Value)) Then _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = ""
        Exit For
    Else
        Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = "=IFNA(INDEX('PLANNED FOR ARRIVAL'!G:G,MATCH([@REFERENCE],'PLANNED FOR ARRIVAL'!D:D,0)),"""")"
        Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value = Sheets("CHECK IN").Cells(i, x).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

What can I change/add to make this work?

I expect cell f.ex. in row 10, column 4 to remain empty if it was empty before and also the cell in row 10, column 2 was empty.
However the formula IFNA... is inserted in this cell (up until row 100)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from what you provide. Are you certain the cells in Column 2 are actually empty?  And don't contain a non-printing character or a formula?  Also, your code, as written, will STOP and exit the macro when it hits the first pair of empty/blank cells, and not process the rest of the range.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Hey Ron, I am sure there are no characters in those cells, since I clean out the cells which need to be empty first by using

Comment: Sheets("CHECK IN").Range("B4:B1000").Clear
Sheets("CHECK IN").Range("D4:Q1000").Clear

Comment: And I do indeed want the code to stop when it hits the first pair of empty/blank cells

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  I copied your code; change the sheet names, and changed the formula to some string.  It behaved as you expected:  Filled in column D where there were non-blanks in either Col B or Col D and then stopped.

Comment: I would suggest putting a break point in the code and examining the contents of cells at the iteration where you expect them both to be blank/empty.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ron! Since I'm not an expert in VBA yet, could you give me an example of the breakpoint you would insert as well as the location where you would put it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would put it on the line of your first `IF` statement. You can then examine the contents of the cells in the locals and/or watches windows. Do an internet search for `vba breakpoint` to see how it is done.

Comment: Also, perhaps there is code between your `.Clear` statements and your posted code that is putting something into those cells.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

1. replace `IsEmpty` with `LenB(Trim(...)` as it can process "invisible" chars that may come up when importing or copying data from an external source
2. use `Cells().FormulaLocal` when inserting formula into a cell
3. use a var for sheet reference which is correct in your case but it takes too much typing and chance of error
4. use `With` when working with a single sheet/workbook/etc

So the code would look like this:

```
Sub ActionCI()

Dim sh as WorkSheet

i = 4
x = 4

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK IN")

With sh
    For i = 4 To 100
        If LenB(Trim(.Cells(i, x).Value)) = 0 And _
           LenB(Trim(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, x).ClearContents ' it is a copy from code but makes no sense for the cell is empty anyway
            Exit For
        Else
            .Cells(i, x).FormulaLocal = "=IFNA(INDEX('PLANNED FOR ARRIVAL'!G:G,MATCH([@REFERENCE],'PLANNED FOR ARRIVAL'!D:D,0)),"""")"
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: They are not equivalent. `LenB(Trim(cell_ref))=0` will return `True` if the cell contains a formula, space, or null string, whereas `IsEmpty(cell_ref)` will return `False`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Absolutely true. But in this particular case I suppose the raw data from some external source does not contain formulas (@CoKa is going to insert them) but it does contain useless spaces, nullstrings or some other whitespaces that can be efficiently detected with `LenB(Trim(`

Comment: In the meanwhile I received the tip that it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using tables. I have changed the range of my tables and it does indeed seem to work now